# Hierarchical scale_fill_* colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-col

I'm wondering if anyone has an easy way to have each category be a separate color scale.

ie: "Forb" would be all shades of blue and green, "Conifer" would be reds, "Shrub" orange and yellow, "Graminoids" purple and pink (or whatever, exact colors don't matter, just that each grouping be distinctly different from the others).

Sample data:

```
structure(list(identifier = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 17L, 7L, 4L, 11L, 
20L, 24L, 8L, 18L, 22L, 10L, 15L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 23L, 34L, 14L, 
12L, 16L, 42L, 43L, 30L, 38L, 29L, 33L, 28L, 27L), SPP = c("Penstemon", 
"Rosaceae Group 1", "Saxifraga OR Micranthes OR Boykinia", "Eriogonum", 
"Boykinia OR Saxifraga", "Vaccinium", "Hypericum", "Chamerion OR Epilobium OR Oenothera", 
"Aster Group 2", "Chrysosplenium tetrandum", "Oenothera", "Aster Group 1", 
"Poaceae", "Chamerion", "Luzula", "Abies", "Oxyria digyna", "Pinus", 
"Castilleja", "Erigeron", "Ribes", "Thalictrum", "Salix", "Xerophyllum tenax", 
"Valeriana", "Rhododendron", "Caryophyllaceae", "Sedum lanceolatum", 
"Senecio", "Polygonaceae", "Phrymaceae"), max = c(0.520063568, 
0.479127183, 0.434079314, 0.362801825, 0.217608897, 0.191388889, 
0.717687654, 0.120278432, 0.140414455, 0.078553735, 0.219305556, 
0.437633588, 0.184346498, 0.383032052, 0.178396573, 0.503981446, 
0.263381525, 0.358707915, 0.165725191, 0.046200125, 0.350292287, 
0.644661654, 0.2640831, 0.016758773, 0.021521319, 0.039176109, 
0.031850659, 0.202567022, 0.067327894, 0.20080737, 0.331692794
), readsum = c(6.716942576, 5.503499137, 3.49976764, 2.309000619, 
1.103758598, 1.913782497, 3.798417906, 1.263140584, 0.76553868, 
0.574245876, 1.616440058, 0.866744904, 0.635800875, 1.478810665, 
1.124030263, 3.881683753, 1.59921115, 1.247338241, 0.634873939, 
0.234050052, 1.246069294, 1.262268812, 1.124014166, 0.097837052, 
0.092817485, 0.344979525, 0.183615231, 0.353545529, 0.246583949, 
0.386051108, 0.390301853), funct_type = c("Forb", "Forb", "Forb", 
"Forb", "Forb", "Shrub", "Forb", "Forb", "Forb", "Forb", "Forb", 
"Forb", "Graminoid", "Forb", "Graminoid", "Conifer", "Forb", 
"Conifer", "Forb", "Forb", "Shrub", "Forb", "Shrub", "Forb", 
"Forb", "Shrub", "Forb", "Forb", "Forb", "Forb", "Forb"), frequencyformula = c(52L, 
50L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 42L, 41L, 
41L, 40L, 40L, 37L, 37L, 36L, 30L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 23L, 
22L, 22L, 20L, 18L), frequency = c(1, 0.961538462, 0.903846154, 
0.903846154, 0.903846154, 0.884615385, 0.865384615, 0.865384615, 
0.865384615, 0.846153846, 0.826923077, 0.826923077, 0.807692308, 
0.788461538, 0.788461538, 0.769230769, 0.769230769, 0.711538462, 
0.711538462, 0.692307692, 0.576923077, 0.557692308, 0.557692308, 
0.519230769, 0.519230769, 0.480769231, 0.442307692, 0.423076923, 
0.423076923, 0.384615385, 0.346153846)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

and my code so far is

```
top32reads %>%
  mutate(funct_type = fct_reorder(.f = funct_type, .x = -readsum, min)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = funct_type, y = readsum)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = reorder(SPP, -readsum)),color = "black",
           position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) +
  ylab("Sum of read percentages across samples")+
  xlab("OTUs Consumed by Functional Type")+
  ggtitle("Diet by Relative Read Abundance")+
  theme_bw()+scale_fill_viridis_d()+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold", family = "Caladea"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 18, face="bold", family = "Caladea"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 28, face = "bold", family = "Caladea", hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold", family = "Caladea")
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your use case it's natively supported by `gpplot2`'s `scale_fill_*` (but I'm happy to be proven wrong).
What I would do is calculating the desired color "manually", and then use those with a `scale_fill_identity`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(colorspace)

df %>%
  mutate(funct_type = fct_reorder(.f = funct_type, .x = -readsum, min),
         main_color = brewer_pal("qual")(n_distinct(funct_type))[funct_type]
         ) %>%
  group_by(funct_type) %>% 
  mutate(lvl = as.integer(fct_reorder(SPP, -readsum)),
         relvl = rescale(lvl, c(0, .6), from = c(0, max(length(lvl), 5))),
         sub_color = darken(main_color, relvl)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = funct_type, y = readsum)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = sub_color),
           position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  ylab("Sum of read percentages across samples") +
  xlab("OTUs Consumed by Functional Type") +
  ggtitle("Diet by Relative Read Abundance") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold", family = "Caladea"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 18, face="bold", family = "Caladea"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 28, face = "bold", family = "Caladea", hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold", family = "Caladea")
  )
```

[image]

I tried to split the variables in the `mutate` step, but you can condense those if you prefer.

With some massaging you can achieve some improved results, particularly in the choice of `main_colors`, and then I bet some improvements and more freedom can be achieved in the choice of `sub_color`s.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this is a great solution (I certainly wouldn't have figured how to do it manually on my own!). but- where does the legend disappear to? one of the reasons I wanted to do it with discrete colors was to make the legend easier to interpret. I tried a few varieties of legend.position, but it still just... wasn't there ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That's because by default `scale_fill_maual` has `guide = "none"` argument. Are you interested in all the colors or only the "main" ones?